# what is the code to disable "open file" under menu tab in Firefox userChrome.css?

Tags: firefox

I want to disable the open file option in the menu tab in Firefox. I have written

```
menuitem[label=Open File]{
display:none;
}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
#menu_openFile { display: none !important }
```

in `userChrome.css`. Keep

```
@namespace xul url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);
```

as the very first line.

[image: How it looks]

Exactly the same process is used to remove `Email links ...`

Add

```
#menu_sendLink { display: none !important }
```

to remove that:

[image: With Email link ...]

After making the change to userChrome.css and restarting the browser, we see that `Email link ...` is removed:

[image: Without Email link ...]

Comment: Its not working

Comment: yes bose, i am able to disable the menu items which don't have (dotdotdot) extension. but there are few menuitems "Send link..."with (3 dots) as extension i.e ellipse extension.how to disable these menuitems.

Comment: Thank you bose, can you tell how to disable the menu items with ... extension.

Comment: ok sure not from next time