# how to disable menu items with ... extension in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, menu

i want to disable the menu items with (dotted) extension i.e. 3 dots. like Send Link, Save Page As.

Comment: @DK Bose can you please check once.

Comment: I edited my answer to your original question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/420772/what-is-the-code-to-disable-open-file-under-menu-tab-in-firefox-userchrome-css/420831#420831).